# Using opencv with Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am planning to use the the camera sensor on Gazebo and use the image from the sensor to perfrom simple image processing like tracking a ball etc. I am planning to use OpenCV libraries. I am very new with opencv, so will I be able to use Opencv libraries ? If so what are the things that I should take care off. I just installed opencv from the following link.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

-Thanks
Bharadwaj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2640/using-opencv-with-gazebo-!/) by [Bharadwaj Ramesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/154/bharadwaj-ramesh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use any library, including opencv, inside a gazebo plugin. There is nothing special you have to do.

I do suggest you use ROS.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0